# MySQL: How to create a fuzzy LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, offset

I need to use LIMIT to return 5 records that increment with an offset every time the function is called, but I want to use a Fuzzy LIMIT.

This fuzzy LIMIT should be affected by one Column A with the entire query sorted by Col A Ascending.

This means, that although the LIMIT is 5, if it were to encounter multiple instances of the SAME VALUE in Col A, it should temporarily increase the LIMIT to encompass all records till the end of that same value.

It should also return some kind of pointer to say that the LIMIT has been temporarily increased by this much, so the next OFFSET can be sent accordingly.

In the below example, if the LIMIT were to fall on record number 5, it should instead include all till record 7. (Because 3 has the same value till 7.)

```
Col A

1

2

3

3

3

3

3

4

5

6
```

How can we create such a LIMIT?
I would be really grateful it if someone could create a query for me, as I'm new to MySQL.

I currently have the normal query:

```
select table1.colA, table1.colB, table1.colC, table1.colD, table2.colD, table2.colE from table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.colD = table2.colD ORDER BY table1.colA ASC
```

Comment: You'll want to group by the column in question, select the top 5 from the grouped query, and then join the original table to that sub query.

Comment: mysql's limit values do not accept dynamic values (e.g. sql variables, expressions, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do it this way:

```
select colA
from t cross join
     (select max(colA) as maxcolA
      from (select colA
            from t
            order by colA
            limit 5
           ) t
      ) const
where colA <= maxColA
order by colA
```

That is, find the value at the 5th row, then use that value in a comparison.

In most other databases, you can phrase this more simply as:

```
select colA
from t
where colA in (select colA from t order by colA limit 5)
order by colA
```

But, MySQL doesn't allow limits in subqueries used in `in` clauses.